# mount.nfs: mount system call failed

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, mount, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to mount hdfs on my local machine running Ubuntu using the following command :---

```
sudo mount -t  nfs  -o vers=3,proto=tcp,nolock 192.168.170.52:/ /mnt/hdfs_mount/
```

But I am getting this error:-

```
mount.nfs: mount system call failed
```

Output for

```
rpcinfo -p 192.168.170.52
```

is

```
        program vers proto   port  service
        100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
        100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
        100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
        100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
        100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
        100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
        100024    1   udp  48435  status
        100024    1   tcp  54261  status
        100005    1   udp   4242  mountd
        100005    2   udp   4242  mountd
        100005    3   udp   4242  mountd
        100005    1   tcp   4242  mountd
        100005    2   tcp   4242  mountd
        100005    3   tcp   4242  mountd
        100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
```

Output for

```
showmount -e 192.168.170.52
```

is

```
Export list for 192.168.170.52:
/ *
```

I also tried by adding

```
<property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>
```

in my core-site.xml file located in /etc/hadoop/conf.pseudo. But it did not work.

Output for :-

```
sudo mount -v -t  nfs  -o vers=3,proto=tcp,nolock 192.168.170.52:/ /mnt/hdfs_mount/
```

is:---

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Jun 29 09:46:30 2017
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=3,proto=tcp,nolock,addr=192.168.170.52'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.170.52 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.170.52 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 4242
mount.nfs: mount(2): Input/output error
mount.nfs: mount system call failed
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: what do you see with 'mount -v -t nfs ....'

Comment: It's 2017, stop using nfs3.

Answer (score 2):

what @84104 is saying is true but I manage to start it with following config/steps :

1. install nfs
2. change /etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml

   ```
   <property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.YOUR_HOSTNAME_NAME.hosts</name>
     <value>*</value>
   </property>

   <property>
     <name>nfs.superuser</name>
     <value>spark</value>
   </property>
   ```
3. change /etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

   ```
   <property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups</name>
     <value>*</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
     <value>*</value>
   </property>
   ```
4. stop hadoop
5. start hadoop
6. `mount -t nfs -o vers=3,proto=tcp,nolock,noacl,sync YOUR_HOSTNAME_NAME:/ /data/hdfs/ -v`